# Python - Selenium (find elements by CSS selector)

Tags: python, css, selenium

**How do I access the first element of an array using a CSS selector in python?**

For Example:

`css=('.od-FieldEditor-fieldTitle.ms-Label.is-required')` returns an array of 6 labels. I want to access the `innerText` attribute of the first label.

[Image shows the array of labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XznCL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('selector_required')


# if you want to navigate through
for e in elements:
    # do some stuffs with 'e'

# to access a single object
e = elements[0] # will return the first element of a list
```